# Is there a difference whether using await with return in Dart?

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, async-await

In my flutter project, say there's a `foo(int x) async` function. And `bar() async` that looks like:

```
Future bar() async {
  return foo(3);
}
```

The `bar()` function is just a simple capsule for `foo(int x)` with a certain parameter. And `bar()` is used as the `future` in a `FutureBuilder`.

I'm not sure if I should use `await` with return. I can't find related documentations online. So what's the difference between `return foo(3)` and `return await foo(3)`? Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No difference whatsoever.

Technically, using `await` first might wait for the `Future` to resolve before returning from the function, but you won't be able to tell the difference.

A `Future` is returned either way.

The `async` there is useless too, it might as well just be an arrow:

```dart
Future bar() => foo(3);
```

If it were not the last statement, and a return statement, this could matter, as pointed out in the comments, take the following:

```dart
Future bar() async {
    try {
        return await foo(3);
    } catch(error) {
        return baz;
    }
}
```

If foo rejects, then it matters quite a lot, as it would be handled by the callee, not the caller.

Comment: What if the await throws an exception?

Comment: @user2864740 If it is a direct `return`, the caller deals with it. If it were another position, it would definitely matter. Updating example to show this.

Comment: To add more details to the last note. In the ```try catch``` block, it's always the ```bar()``` method which will catch the error, and it's not related to the ```await``` keyword.

Comment: I did some testing - as near as I can tell, uneccesarily awaiting a Future instead of simply returning it costs around 200 nanoseconds, when the calls are completed synchronously (i.e. when there not actually anything to wait for, e.g. when a Completer is already complete), but any time asynchronicity is actually used (e.g. a 0-millisecond Future.delayed) the cost in either case jumps to about 30 microseconds, dwarfing any difference between the two.  Your specific mileage may vary, though I'd expect the general result to remain true in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are returning Future, in this exact case, even if you don`t await it, the foo(3) will return Future instead and it is the exact thing your function wants to return. and if u await it there, then it will await in the function and then return the value.

you don`t even need  await in this case if foo return Future. Then the caller of bar will instead await the bar.

Answer (score 0):

Using this simple example you can see in which order prints yield:

```
Future<void> fetchUserOrder() {
  return Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () => print('Large Latte'));
}

void main() async {
  await fetchUserOrder();
  print('Fetching user order...');
}
```

`fetchUserOrder()` returns `Future`. So if we call it in main with `await`, it will receive the `Future`, execute it and await for the result. Only then proceed to the second `print` of the main.

We could've written the `fetchUserOrder()` in such a fashion:

```
Future<void> fetchUserOrder() async {
  return await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () => print('Large Latte'));
}
```

And it wouldn't have had changed the result. It would work the same, the only difference is shorter code and that now you understand how it works.

Use https://dartpad.dev/ to launch these examples.